# Range name created by QueryTable in Excel VBA macos

Tags: mysql, vba, macos, excel-2016, named-ranges

I am running a QueryTable in Excel for Mac 2016, with destination to range 'data_value', name for cell A1 in spreadsheet 'hs', QueryTable assigns the name 'ExternalData_1' to the same cell A1 after extracting the data, I want to delete name 'ExternalData_1' so I can refer to the value in 'data_value' at the end of the script but can't.

```vb
Function get_data(input_id As String, input_date As String)

Dim sqlstring As String
Dim connstring As String
Dim sLogin As String

 sLogin = "DATABASE=[DB];UID=[USER];PWD=[PWD]"
sqlstring = "SELECT data_value FROM tb_data_values WHERE data_date='" & input_date & "'"
connstring = "ODBC;DSN=myodbc;" & sLogin

With
    Worksheets("hs").QueryTables.Add(Connection:=connstring, Destination:=Range("data_value"), Sql:=sqlstring)
   .FieldNames = False
   .BackgroundQuery = False
   .Refresh
   .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells

End With

get_data = Range("data_value")

Dim qt As QueryTable
For Each qt In Worksheets("hs").QueryTables
   qt.Delete
Next qt

Worksheets("hs").Names("ExternalData_1").Delete
Worksheets("hs").Range("data_value").ClearContents

End Function
```

VBA stops running in line `Worksheets("hs").Names("ExternalData_1").Delete`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply remove that line. When you delete each QueryTable, you already delete its named range. Therefore, your call `Worksheets("hs").Names("ExternalData_1").Delete` is redundant and would error out since *Name* object does not exist. Had you wrapped function in proper error handling, the error would raise:

> Application-defined or Object-defined error

To test, run a `Name` range loop just after your `QueryTables` loop. From below, you would see that only one "ExternalData_1" will print with `Debug.Print`.

```vb
Dim qt As QueryTable, RngName As Name

For Each qt In Worksheets("hs").QueryTables
    Debug.Print qt.Name                           ' "ExternalData_1" WILL PRINT
    qt.Delete
Next qt

For Each RngName In Worksheets("hs").Names
    Debug.Print RngName.Name                      ' "ExternalData_1" WILL NOT PRINT
Next RngName
```

Alternatively, you can check after running code without line above under Ribbon > Formulas > Name Manager (under Defined Names section) (may differ on Mac), and see ""ExternalData_1" not listed.

[image: Excel Ribbon Show]

Comment: Thank you. Deleted the line and the script worked fine, however the names are still there. The first qt loop indeed only printed the last QueryTable's name 'ExternalData_5', but the Name range loop printed all names from 'ExternalData_1' to 'ExternalData_5' from previous QueryTables. Also, QueryTable is inserting a cell, that I understand should not be done because I set `code` .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells.

Comment: Those previous names may be from prior code runs. Manually delete them all and try again. When name exists, new name increments by 1. As for *inserting a cell*, reverse the order by placing `.RefresheStyle ...` before `.Refresh`.

Comment: Thank you. Did it, even closed the file and reopened it again, manually deleted all names, run the script, name are still somewhere. First qt loop prints the last 'ExternalData_X', the name range loop prints all names 'hs!ExternalData_1'...'hs!ExternalData_X'. Thank you for the .RefreshStyle comment.

Comment: Only one QueryTable. This is the only script in the Workbook, it connects to an external mySQL database, I don't know of any other QueryTable or connection to the database.

Comment: Again, I am unable to reproduce. But I am on Windows. Maybe ODBC calls run differently. Try re-running from an empty workbook.

Comment: I was able to delete all range names by calling external data to a ListObject, not a QueryTable. By deleting the List Object `Worksheets("hs").ListObjects(1).Delete` the script deletes all names associated with the ListObject table and closes the database connection.

Comment: Interesting. Are you sure posted code is actually what you are using? No `ListObjects.Add(...) .QueryTable` in a previous code run? Did you try posted code in a completely new, empty workbook? Sometimes Excel caches objects in used workbooks.

Comment: Yes, I tried, and never was able to get rid off the names using QueryTable.

Comment: There were as many names as QueryTables I called up to that point without deleting them manually. I will try running it in Windows. Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like you did not test this code in a completely **new** workbook? Please copy your code into the VBA editor of a new, blank workbook and re-run macro. Create only the *data_value* named range as needed in code.

Comment: The only way it worked was making reference to the QueryTable explicitly `ActiveSheet.QueryTables(1).Delete` and only one spreadsheet in the Workbook.